# pagination not working on custom action in Magento

Tags: magento, module, action, paging, issue-tracking

> i am facing a very strange issue which is i am using a extension which
>   shows all news products .
>
> you can see the link
>   https://www.furnituregossip.co.uk/dev/catalogextensions/index/newproduct/
>
> but the problem is paging is not working as it should be
>
> . The paging is working fine on magento default categories created
>   from admin please see below link
>   http://www.furnituregossip.co.uk/dev/living-room-furniture.html on
>   this the paging is working fine.

But on  https://www.furnituregossip.co.uk/dev/catalogextensions/index/newproduct/ when i hover over the paging links it shows the page id in url but when i click on the paging link it doesn’t add any parameter in the url like ?p=1 .

> If i manually add parameter in the url like ?p=1 or something than it
>   work fine.

THe config file of module is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creative_Catalogextensions>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Creative_Catalogextensions>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <catalogextensions>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Creative_Catalogextensions</module>
                    <frontName>catalogextensions</frontName>
                </args>
            </catalogextensions>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <catalogextensions>
                    <file>catalogextensions/catalogextensions.xml</file>
                </catalogextensions>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <catalogextensions>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Creative_Catalogextensions</module>
                    <frontName>catalogextensions</frontName>
                </args>
            </catalogextensions>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
       <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <catalogextensions translate="title" module="catalogextensions">
                                            <title>Catalogextensions Configuration</title>
                                        </catalogextensions>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                        <Creative_Catalogextensions>
                            <title>Catalogextensions Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Creative_Catalogextensions>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <catalogextensions>
                    <file>catalogextensions.xml</file>
                </catalogextensions>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalogextensions>
                <class>Creative_Catalogextensions_Block</class>
            </catalogextensions>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <catalogextensions>
                <class>Creative_Catalogextensions_Helper</class>
            </catalogextensions>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <catalogextensions>
            <config4>
                <active>0</active>
                <max_product>3</max_product>
                <title>New Products</title>
                <type>Recently Added</type>
            </config4>
        </catalogextensions>
    </default>
</config>
```

Please suggest me how can i fix this. I also cant understandf why the new action redirects on secure url may be that can be the issue also.

Comment: In the Pagination URL, you can see its `catalogextensions1` while it should be `catalogextensions`. Also if the URL becomes `http://www.furnituregossip.co.uk/dev/catalogextensions/index/newproduct/?p=2` instead of 'http://www.furnituregossip.co.uk/dev/catalogextensions1/index/newproduct/?p=2', it will work

Comment: HI i cant see catalogextensions1 in paging url  but now i have fix the issue by changing the admin router name.Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i have fix the issue by changing the admin router name in the config file. I have folow this post.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/problem-with-custom-module-url-redirects-http-to-https/5967#5967

thanks